# Soft absolute value

Tags: numerical-methods, absolute-value

I'm looking for a "soft absolute value" function that is numerically stable. What I mean by that is that the function should have $\mp x$ asymptotes at $\mp\infty$ and behave smoothly in $[-1,1]$.

One easy solution is to integrate $\tanh(x)$, giving $f(x) = \ln(\cosh(x))$, but this formula leads to unnecessary numerical issues for large values of $\|x\|$. Any suggestion greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can convolve $|x|$ with some smooth kernel, like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})$

Comment: @uranix That's a good idea, but ideally I need an analytical formula for this function; would there be one with this kernel?

Comment: $$
f(y) =y \text{erf}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sigma  e^{-\frac{y^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}
$$

Comment: :) Nice, I also got another answer on my side

Comment: Do you need a smooth function? Or just e.g. twice differentiable?

Comment: For all intents and purposes, twice differentiable should be enough, but if we can find a smooth one it's always better!

Comment: Consider then this simple function $$f(y) = \begin{cases}|y|, &|y| > \delta\\\frac{y^2 +\delta^2}{2\delta}&|y| \leq \delta\end{cases}$$

Comment: @uranix:  that does not go through $(0,0)$.  It is not clear if that is a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually integrating the logistic function gives a better result in terms of numerical stability:
$$
\int\left( \frac{2}{1+e^{-x}}-1\right) dx = 2J - x + C_1
$$
with
$$
J = \int \frac{dx}{1+e^{-x}} = x + \int\frac{-e^{-x}dx}{1+e^{-x}} = x + \ln(1+e^{-x}) + C_2
$$
which put back in the former integral yields
$$
f(x) = x + 2\ln\left(\frac{1+e^{-x}}{2}\right) \quad\text{with}\quad f(0)=0
$$

This is only stable for $x\in[0,+\infty)$, but fortunately $f$ is symmetric
$$
f(-x) = -x + 2\ln\left( e^x\frac{e^{-x}+1}{2} \right) = f(x)
$$
so numeric calculations can be made stable on $(-\infty,0]$.

---

In short, a numerically stable smooth absolute value function is:
$$
  f(x) = |x| + 2\ln\left(\frac{1+e^{-|x|}}{2}\right)
$$

Comment: That looks like $-\ln 2$ at $x\rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: @uranix I missed a 2... Let me fix that

Comment: Basically, that is just a more stable formula for $2\ln \cosh \frac{x}{2}$

Comment: But we can use the fact that it is symmetric to avoid these problems :)

Answer (score 4):

One of the easiest possibilities is to perturb $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ a  little bit to
$$
f_ε(x)=\sqrt{x^2+ε^2}
$$
The asymptotics can be derived from
$$
0\le f_ε(x)-|x|=\frac{ε^2}{\sqrt{x^2+ε^2}+|x|}\le \frac{ε^2}{2|x|}
$$
If one wants to get a function that has value zero at zero use
$$
g_ε(x)=f_ε(x)-ε.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Depends maybe on what you mean by smooth, but what about
$$
\frac{a|x|^3}{1+ax^2}?
$$
For $a=10$, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) As I said in comment, the smoother the better, although twice differentiable should be enough in practice.

Comment: I came up with a smooth answer below if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks, you are the one who should be happy... Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

How smooth do you need?  Is continuous first derivatives enough?  You can fit a quartic through $(-1,1), (0,0), (1,1)$ and demand the proper derivative at $-1,1$. This gives $$y=ax^4+bx^2\\a+b=1\\4a+2b=1\\a=-\frac 12\\b=\frac 32$$ where there is no constant term to go through $(0,0)$ and the function is even because there are no odd order terms.  This gives a simple expression.

Comment: Do we need to go through $(0,0)$?  A similar approach using sixth degree (only three parameters) can get you continuous second derivatives at the match points.

Comment: Thanks! Yes it needs to go through $(0,0)$, I should have thought about fitting a polynomial.. Bezier curves might also be a possibility.

Comment: Of all the other non-smooth approaches, I think this is the best, but my answer below gives a smooth and stable answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest is the following:

$$f(x) = x \coth(\alpha x),$$

for some $\alpha$ that you may choose at your convenience. The larger $\alpha$, the closer you are to the true absolute value.

You should be able to resolve any remaining numerical issue at small $x$ with a Taylor expansion.

Comment: Thanks Ben, looks like any practical implementation of this would probably need branches to handle numerical instabilities near zero. See my answer above for a smooth and numerically stable alternative: $f(x) = |x| + 2\ln\left(\frac{1 + e^{-|x|}}{2}\right)$